# Why does the ubuntu one iPad App only work with activated Location Services?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I got an iPad as a present. Being a typical nerd, of course I deactivated the location services. I especially don't want my published photos to contain location information.

Now the Ubuntu one iPad app won't let me add files or folders if I won't activate these services.

1. for what purpose does this app want these features? The android app that does the same, does not need location services.
2. is there a workaround allowing me to upload anything without those services?

Thanks,

Paddy

Answer (score 2):

In order for the automatic upload feature to access your photos without forcing you to choose each one, it has to have access to all the photos in your library. To get this access, iOS requires the app to be granted access to the location services, because some of those photos might have location information.

Unfortunately, although the Ubuntu One iOS app doesn't ever access your current location, iOS requires that the location services be on in order to get that authorization, and remain on while it accesses your photos.

You may wish to enable location services and simply disable it for most apps. The iOS 6 System Settings > Privacy > Location Services screen lets you disable access for apps that have requested it, and for some system services.